# JBoss 6.1.0.Final and ActiveMQ 5.6.0 - any way to work around AMQ-3868?

Tags: jboss, activemq-classic

I would ideally like to add ActiveMQ 5.6.0 to my JBoss 6.1.0.Final.

But then you will of course hit: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AMQ-3868

Due to some library conflicts.

Is there any way to use the classloading isolation to work around this issue? Or any other way to work around this issue?